# What is the meaning of General - {0}, and can we put other numbers instead of 0, and does this "Format" means formatting of the image

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I'm Using ASP.NET. In the ItemTemplate of the DataList I dragged an image. In the imageURL, field binding, the Format = none or General - {0}. I want to know what is the meaning of General - {0}, and can we put other numbers instead of 0.
Another issue is does this "Format" means formatting of the image or what?

Comment: if you have follow up questions, please use the comments. If you feel you need to clarify your question, please edit it. Otherwise, please accept the answer that helped you. Also, post some actual code so that we can see exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing more than a format string, such as the kind used by the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) method. In this case, it is used to allow the URL to be constructed from a combination of constants and data.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically set around zero based string arrays.

```
var first = "first";    // {0}
var second = "second";  // {1}
var third = "third";    // {2}
string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}.", first, second, third)
// first, second, third.
```

or

```
var strings = new [] {
    "first",   // {0}
    "second",  // {1}
    "third"};  // {2}
string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}.", strings);
// first, second, third.
```

are the same thing

also, this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.dataimageurlformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might lend a little more info.

Essentially if you have to create a URL on the fly, you'll use a formatted string.

```
var urlFormat = "http://example.com/images/{0}.jpg";
var image = "image1";
var imageUrl = string.Format(urlFormat, image);
// http://example.com/images/image1.jpg
```